# On a proof that if $x>3$ then $x^2 >9$.

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I am new to mathematical proofs and I don't understand the following. I want to prove that if $x>3$ then $x^2 >9$. My textbook proves it as follows: $x=3+y$ for some $y>0$ and hence $x^2 = 9 + 6y + y^2 > 9$. Okay that makes sense. But why do we not just square $x>3$ such that we obtain $x^2 > 9$ right away? Why overcomplicate things?

Comment: Note that $(-1) > (-2)$ does *not* imply $(-1)^2 > (-2)^2$.

Comment: When does squaring work? $x^2-y^2=(x-y)(x+y)$, so if $x>y$ and $x+y>0$, then $x^2>y^2$.

Comment: @MartinR okay but we already know that $x>3$ so $(-3)$ is not an option anymore.

Comment: Yes, because $x\ge 0$ and $3\ge0$, squaring the inequality is valid.

Comment: A case can be made that your approach would be assuming what you are trying to prove.  Presumably, the book intended that you apply the basic ideas that [1] $~(r > s) \iff (r-s > 0)~$ and [2] $~(r,s > 0) \implies [(r\times s) > 0].$